# Arraylist, incomparable types: DieClass and int

Tags: java, methods, for-loop, arraylist, dice

Trying to write a program that "rolls" dice and displays the results of the players and computer's rolls, as well as find how many of each number was rolled. Say, player rolls 3 4 3 5 6, then the player has a match composed of 2 3's. Haven't wrote the code to display the matching yet.

My problem is that I am trying to record the rolls to an `ArrayList`, then compare each number for the players and computers rolls from the `ArrayList`, and count up the number of each number's occurrence, but it I keep getting the error of

> error: incomparable types: DieClass and int

Whenever I try to compare from the ArrayList

The program in question uses methods from the class `DieClass`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DieTester
{
private static ArrayList<DieClass> player = new ArrayList<DieClass>();
private static ArrayList<DieClass> computer = new ArrayList<DieClass>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        DieClass roller = new DieClass();
        player.add(roller);
    }
    for(int a = 1; a <= 5; a++)
    {
        DieClass roller = new DieClass();
        computer.add(roller);
    }
    System.out.println("The user rolls: "+player);
    System.out.println("The computer rolls: "+computer);
}

public String findMatching()
{
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<player.size(); i++)
    {
        if(player.get(i)==1)
        {
            count1++;
        }
        else if(player.get(i)==2)
        {
            count2++;
        }
        else if(player.get(i)==3)
        {
            count3++;
        }
        else if(player.get(i)==4)
        {
            count4++;
        }
        else if(player.get(i)==5)
        {
            count5++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=1; i<player.size(); i++)
    {
        if(computer.get(i)==1)
        {
            count1++;
        }
        else if(computer.get(i)==2)
        {
            count2++;
        }
        else if(computer.get(i)==3)
        {
            count3++;
        }
        else if(computer.get(i)==4)
        {
            count4++;
        }
        else if(computer.get(i)==5)
        {
            count5++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: DieClasses won't unbox into Integers. If that class has a `getFace()/getNumber()` or whatever method you have to get the `int` it is storing (if any), use that to check.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are comparing DieClass with Integers

```
 if(player.get(i)==1)
```

For the counters, why don't you use an array of int? like

```
int counters [] = new int[6]; 

counters[2]++;
```

Please post DieClass, however, I think that your code should be like this.

```
for (DieClass dieClass : player) {          
counters[dieClass.getNumber()-1]++; //Supose that DieClass has a getNumber method and set minus one because counters goes from 0 to 5
}
```